# What is WSO2 oauth2 authorize endpoint in

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

```
https://localhost:9443/authenticationendpoint/login.doresponse_type=code&client_id=myclient_id&scope=profile&redirect_uri=http://localhost/gatewaytest/Home/WsoCallBack
```

Here is my authorize endpoint. When I run this I get errors like

> Error 405 - Method Not Allowed

I have already setup wso2 identity server and admin console in my machine.
Any reason for this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following URL by replacing values for `<client_id>`, `<redirect_uri>`, and `<scope>`.

```
https://localhost:9443/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=<client_id>&redirect_uri=<redirect_uri>&scope=<scope>
```

Refer https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/try-authorization-code-grant/ for more details.

Comment: when i run below link, this "HTTP STATUS 404-Not Found" appears. What is wrong here.

https://localhost:9443/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=<client_id>&redirect_uri=<redirect_uri>&scope=

Comment: this worked for me. There was issue with my server version. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

[image: http error message]

when i run below link, this message appears. What is wrong here.

https://localhost:9443/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=<client_id>&redirect_uri=<redirect_uri>&scope=